# The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm creating a report in Reporting Services, I need a query to return a list of values, a count of each of the individual values, and the results of those values from a table-valued function.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT        Samples.Value, COUNT(Samples.Value) AS count, pdf.within, pdf.overall
FROM            Samples,dbo.PDFunction(Samples.Value,@Mean,@StDevOverall,@StDevWithin) as pdf
WHERE        (Samples.SampledAt >= @StartDate) AND (Samples.SampledAt <= @EndDate) AND (Samples.ProductId = @ProductID) AND (Samples.TestId = @TestID) AND 
                         (Samples.SetEnum > 0) AND (Samples.Value IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY Samples.Value
```

This returns the following error:
The multi-part identifier "Samples.Value" could not be bound.
It's talking about the Samples.Value parameter in the dbo.PDFunction() call

Can anyone help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a CROSS APPLY to pass in the `Samples.value` to your function, this assumes the function is a table-valued function:

```
SELECT Samples.Value, 
  COUNT(Samples.Value) AS count, 
  pdf.within, 
  pdf.overall
FROM Samples
CROSS APPLY dbo.PDFunction(Samples.Value,@Mean,@StDevOverall,@StDevWithin) as pdf
WHERE (Samples.SampledAt >= @StartDate) 
  AND (Samples.SampledAt <= @EndDate) 
  AND (Samples.ProductId = @ProductID) 
  AND (Samples.TestId = @TestID) 
  AND (Samples.SetEnum > 0) 
  AND (Samples.Value IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY Samples.Value, pdf.within, pdf.overall
```